# Javascript: access to this inside prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I extend an object by using prototype. Using this inside nested functions does not refer to the object that is inherited but to the function itself.

The plugin i try to extend has an implementation of prototype already so there is a need to define a new object 'hungry':

```
var oSausage=function() {
    this.preference='hotdog';
}

oSausage.prototype.hungry={
    getPreference:function() {
        console.log(this.preference)
    },
    another:function() {

    },
    .....
}
```

Is there a way to refer to the object that is extended, i.e. oSausage?

Answer (score 1):

The core issue here is that the `hungry` object is independent of the `oSausage` one. Other objects can own a reference to it too. All `oSausage` has is a reference to it so your `hugry`  object has no 'awareness' about its owner.

You can always keep a reference to it.

You can either do `oSausage.hotdog` directly, or do something like:

```
oSausage.prototype.hungry={
    sausage:oSausage,
    getPreference:function() {
        console.log(this.sausage.hotdog)
    },
    another:function() {

    },
    .....
}
```

Comment: this.sausage inside getPreference() refers to the function oSausage but not to the object itself. I'd like to access to the properties ob the object - you see a chance to do so?

Comment: @campari Let me see if I understand what you mean, all the oSausage objects share a single hungry object, which has functions that when invoked should access the properties of the particular invoking oSausage object?

Comment: (edit: pressed return)
oSausage is invoked once and functions of hungry object should access to properties of oSausage: 
var x = new oSausage();
x.hungry.getPreference();

I'd like to avoid something like this:
oSausage.prototype.getPreference=function() {
 console.log(this.preference)
}
Because there is a need to extend oSausage with lots of functions.

Comment: @campari I think you're mixing some stuff. If you attach an object to a constructor function's prototype, all objects created with it will _share_ that same object. If you meant for _each_ `oSausage` to own a `hungry` member you need to attach it to this in the constructor.